# Java generic solution to result in same behavior but different input

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
Name name = address.getName();
if (null != name && null != name.getFullName()) {
    addressInfo.setName(name.getFullName());
} else {
    addressInfo.setName(StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
Email emailProfile = address.getEmailAddresses();
if (null != emailProfile && emailProfile.hasPrimaryEmail()) {
    addressInfo.setEmail(emailProfile.getPrimaryEmail().getEmailAddress());
} else {
    addressInfo.setEmail(StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
VoicePhone voicePhoneProfile = address.getVoicePhones();
if (null != voicePhoneProfile && voicePhoneProfile.hasPrimaryPhone()) {
    addressInfo.setPhoneNumber(voicePhoneProfile.getPrimaryPhone().getPhoneNumber());
} else {
    addressInfo.setPhoneNumber(StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
```

They are basically doing the same thing but the getter and setter behavior is different.
Is there a way to write one single generic method to make these 3 block of code into 3 lines of code?

Comment: With Java 8, you can do that with a `Predicate`/`Supplier`/`Consumer` combination.

Comment: [Guava has `firstNonNull()` for a reason!](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-) `firstNonNull(name.getFullName(),"")` you can nest them to get parent null behavior as well. All that said, `setXXX` methods are so 2000, immutability is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

I would discourage trying to meld these methods together.  There's a simpler win that you can get here, actually.

Take a closer look at what they're doing:

- `setName` only sets the name to the full name if it exists, otherwise it defaults to "empty".
- `setEmail` only sets the email address if it exists, otherwise it defaults to "empty".
- `setPhoneNumber` only sets the phone number if a primary phone number exists, otherwise it defaults to "empty".

Enforce the defaults **in the bean itself** as opposed to the conditional logic here.

```
public class Name {
    private String name = StringUtils.EMPTY;
}

// and so forth for Email and VoicePhone
```

Comment: This is awkward, because Name, Email, VoicePhone are classes that are not owned by me, I cannot just change them, I can have some wrapper wrap around them but it seems to not worth the effort....